# Proof validation: let G be a finite group, with a subgroup of Index 4. Than G has normal subgroups of index 3 or 2

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, solution-verification, finite-groups

I came across an Algebra exam question and wanted to ask for validation of a proof I wrote.

The question states (in german):

"Let G be a finite group, with a subgroup of Index 4. Show that G has normal subgroups of index 3 or 2."

Proof:

Let G be a finite Group and H a subgroup with (G : H) = 4

A group homomorphism is given because G acts on the cosets of H by left multiplication.

$$\varphi :G \mapsto Sym(X)$$
$$g \mapsto L_{g}$$

$$X = \begin{Bmatrix}
H & a_{1}H & a_{2}H & a_{3}H
\end{Bmatrix}$$

$$L_{g}: X \mapsto X,
H \mapsto gH$$

We have that:
$$ker(\varphi)\subseteq H$$

Thus:
$$\left | \frac{G}{ker(\varphi)} \right |
 = \left | G : ker(\varphi) \right | = (G : H)(H :ker(\varphi) ) = 4(H:ker(\varphi))$$

Great! now we know that 4 divides our Quotient:

$$4 \mid  \left | \frac{G}{ker(\varphi)} \right |= \left | im(\varphi) \right | \mid  24 = 3*2^3$$

case 1:

$$ \left | \frac{G}{ker(\varphi)} \right | = 4$$
Then our group H is our whole kernel, but because 4 is 2^2 we have a element with order 2 by cauchy. Thus
$$\Rightarrow \left | \frac{K}{H} \right | = 2 \Rightarrow \frac{\frac{G}{H}}{\frac{K}{H}} \cong \frac{G}{K}\Rightarrow \left | \frac{G}{K} \right | = 2$$

case 2:
$$ \left | \frac{G}{ker(\varphi)} \right | = 8$$
Again we find a subgroup with order 4 that has index 2 in G over ker(phi)

$$\Rightarrow \left | \frac{K}{ker(\varphi)} \right | = 4 \Rightarrow \frac{\frac{G}{ker(\varphi)}}{\frac{K}{ker(\varphi)}} \cong \frac{G}{K}\Rightarrow \left | \frac{G}{K} \right | = 2$$

case 3:
$$ \left | \frac{G}{ker(\varphi)} \right | = 12$$

by sylow I we find a 2-Sylowgroup which is normal and has Index 3 such that:

$$\Rightarrow \left | \frac{K}{ker(\varphi)} \right | = 4 \Rightarrow \frac{\frac{G}{ker(\varphi)}}{\frac{K}{ker(\varphi)}} \cong \frac{G}{K}\Rightarrow \left | \frac{G}{K} \right | = 3$$

case 4:

$$ \left | \frac{G}{ker(\varphi)} \right | = 24$$

We have that A4 lies normal in S4 with index 2.

Thus we found out that with every possible size of the kernel we have found a normal group with index either 2 or 3.

Is this sufficient? And maybe is there a more efficient way to prove this statement? Please excuse my poor latex skills as I am quite new to posting.

Comment: To quote the tag description of [tag:solution-verification]: For posts looking for feedback or verification of a proposed solution. "Is my proof correct?" is off topic (too broad, missing context). Instead, the question must identify precisely which step in the proof is in doubt, and why so.

Comment: The proof looks OK to me.